# SystemMessage in Moqui

Tags: moqui

I was facing issue in understanding the flow of **SystemMessage** in moqui. I thought it would be good to ask if my understanding about it is correct or not. So -

1. There are some important entities related to it, like SystemMessage, SystemMessageType, SystemMessageRemote, ServiceJob, SystemMessageError.
2. Whenever we want to get or fetch the data we have to first receive the data, receive#IncomingSystemMessage service.
3. And if we want to send the data we have to first queue the data for that we use queue#SystemMessage service.
4. These services will create a SystemMessage record in the entity. Which can be process further.
5. The text of info is stored in the messageText field of the SystemMessage entity.
6. While receiving the data by receive#IncomingSystemMessage service the consume#ReceivedSystemMessage service is called to consume the data for create SystemMessage record.
7. And while sending data queue#SystemMessage will check if sendNow is true or false, if it is true then it will call a service named send#ProducedSystemMessage and sends data.
8. The value of sendNow is by default true. We can choose to send the generated system message right now or maybe later.

Want to know, is there something I am missing on, or I have misunderstood ?